# VBAでMSProject内のタスクが無効化されていないか判別したい

Tags: vba

VBAでMSProject内のタスクが無効化されていないか判別したいのですが、どのプロパティを利用すればよいのでしょうか？

参考にしているMicrosoftのデベロッパーセンターにそれらしきプロパティがないので、質問させて頂きました(https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/project.task)。

Comment: [Task. Active プロパティ (Project)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/project.task.active) だと思われます。[Active and inactive tasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office365/servicedescriptions/project-online-service-description/task-management#active-and-inactive-tasks)、「タスクの非アクティブ化」のリンク先、[アクティブ (タスク フィールド)](https://support.office.com/ja-jp/article/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%96-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89-81769c1e-6b4b-4014-bad4-21471fdaa99e) などから推測しました。

Comment: kunifさん > 私の質問に何度も回答して頂き、ありがとうございます。
Activeプロパティで試してみようと思います。